# I installed postrgres.app but `psql` command does not work

Tags: sql, postgresql, terminal, psql

I installed PostgreSQL with Postgress.app and need to import some databases from the command line.

[image: My command line and Postgress.app opened]

This is a screenshot of my command line. In theory, when I type `psql -U postgres -d Employees < employees.sql` the database should be created. But, instead, I receive this message: `zsh: command not found: psql` . I don't know what this message means or what I should do about it. How can I make the `psql` command work? Please somebody explain, I know this must be very basic but I don't understand anything.

And this is what the instructor of the course says should happen:

[image]

Further information:

- I am following the ZeroToMastery course on databases. This is the lesson where I had this error: https://academy.zerotomastery.io/courses/1073491/lectures/23180605
- I have not used the command line or SQL before.

Comment: You need to add it to your `PATH`. it should be something like : `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin:$PATH"` where you replace the `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin` with the folder where you installed it

Comment: it should be covered in the documentation https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

Comment: What is `PATH` ? And how do I know where psql is installed?

Comment: The shell path for a user  is a set of locations in the filing system whereby the user has permissions to use certain applications, commands and programs without the need to specify the full path to that command or program in the Terminal.

Comment: You should know where you installed the application because you were the one that did the install. If you did not change anything, the default should be `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

Comment: Please just try using the instruction on the official documentation I linked above. they should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem thanks to @GabrielDurac. I also finally understood what the `PATH` is. The problem was, the "program" called `psql` was not in the shell `PATH` (i.e. the set of locations where my terminal "programs" are). Therefore, my terminal couldn't access it, so I couldn't open the terminal.

In order to assing my psql "program" to `PATH`, I followed the instructions here: postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

Now, when I try to do the same thing than before, my terminal looks like this. Success!

```
(base) arnau@MacBook-Air-de-Arnau ~ % psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3
(base) arnau@MacBook-Air-de-Arnau ~ % cd Documents
(base) arnau@MacBook-Air-de-Arnau Documents % cd databases 
(base) arnau@MacBook-Air-de-Arnau databases % cd employee
(base) arnau@MacBook-Air-de-Arnau employee % psql -U postgres <Employees.sql
CREATE TYPE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
LOADING departments
INSERT 0 9
LOADING employees
INSERT 0 17944
INSERT 0 17938
INSERT 0 17953
INSERT 0 17947
INSERT 0 17948
INSERT 0 17648
INSERT 0 17642
INSERT 0 17638
INSERT 0 17653
INSERT 0 17650
INSERT 0 17636
INSERT 0 17642
INSERT 0 17646
INSERT 0 17642
INSERT 0 17651
INSERT 0 17637
INSERT 0 16209
LOADING dept_emp
INSERT 0 24940
INSERT 0 24940
INSERT 0 24940
INSERT 0 24934
INSERT 0 24360
INSERT 0 24360
INSERT 0 24360
INSERT 0 24360
INSERT 0 24360
INSERT 0 24360
INSERT 0 24360
INSERT 0 24360
INSERT 0 24360
INSERT 0 12609
LOADING dept_manager
INSERT 0 24
LOADING titles
INSERT 0 21707
INSERT 0 21700
INSERT 0 21687
INSERT 0 21694
INSERT 0 21695
INSERT 0 21700
INSERT 0 21326
INSERT 0 21257
INSERT 0 21245
INSERT 0 21266
INSERT 0 21279
INSERT 0 21251
INSERT 0 21270
INSERT 0 21261
INSERT 0 21251
INSERT 0 21272
INSERT 0 21258
INSERT 0 21252
INSERT 0 21260
INSERT 0 21276
INSERT 0 15401
LOADING salaries
INSERT 0 25526
INSERT 0 25527
INSERT 0 25529
INSERT 0 25527
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25527
INSERT 0 25525
INSERT 0 25531
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25527
INSERT 0 25529
INSERT 0 25525
INSERT 0 25530
INSERT 0 25529
INSERT 0 25529
INSERT 0 25526
INSERT 0 25530
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25527
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25527
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25530
INSERT 0 25526
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25530
INSERT 0 25529
INSERT 0 25530
INSERT 0 25528
INSERT 0 25224
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24923
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24923
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24918
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24918
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24923
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24923
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24918
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24917
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24923
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24924
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24918
INSERT 0 24923
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24924
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 24918
INSERT 0 24921
INSERT 0 24922
INSERT 0 24918
INSERT 0 24923
INSERT 0 24924
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24920
INSERT 0 24919
INSERT 0 7671
(base) arnau@MacBook-Air-de-Arnau employee %
```